# Asymptotic probability concerning the largest absolute value in an iid Gaussian sample

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, extreme-value

Let $v[n]$ be a vector $N$ $iid$ gaussian samples, of ~$N(0,\sigma^2)$ Also, let $v_{max}$ denote the maximum absolute value of all the samples given. (That is, if I took the absolute value of all the $N$ random samples given, and picked the max, that would be $v_{max}$).

I am trying to ascertain why this statement is true:

**In English:**

"The probability of $v_{max}$ exceeding $\sigma \sqrt{2log_e N}$ approaches $0$, as the sample size $N$ approaches infinity."

**In mathematical terms:**

$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} P \left( v_{max} > \sigma \sqrt{2log_e{N}} \right) = 0
$$

I am not even sure where to start on this. Intuitively, I am not even sure why the sample size $N$ should matter, so I do not even have a starting intuitive traction for this particular problem. Would appreciate any insights.

**TLDR: How is the $\sigma \sqrt{2log_e{N}}$ derived exactly?**

---

**Edit, what I have tried so far:**

Thanks to the comments, I have managed to piece together something, but it still seems I am a ways away.

I want to show that $\lim_{N \to \infty} P(v_{max} > z) = 0$ becomes true when $z=\sigma \sqrt{2log_eN})$. Based on the $iid$ assumption, we can say then say that

$$P(v_{max} > z) = P(|v_1|, |v_2|, |v_3| ... |v_N| > z) = \left [2 - 2\Phi_{\sigma}(z) \right]^N$$

, where $\Phi_{\sigma}$ is the [CDF the common gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), given by:

$$
\Phi_{\sigma}(z) = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} erf \left [\frac{z}{\sigma \sqrt{2}} \right]
$$

Then this means, that by simple substitution,

$$
P(v_{max} > z) = \left[1 - erf \left( \frac{z}{\sigma \sqrt{2}}\right) \right]^N
$$

And thus,

$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} P(v_{max} > z) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \left[1 - erf \left( \frac{z}{\sigma \sqrt{2}}\right) \right]^N = 0
$$

Here however I am stuck. How does one show from here that $z=\sigma \sqrt{2log_eN})$?...

Thanks

Comment: For intuition on why the sample size matters, take it to the extreme. Imagine a sample of size 1. Now think about a much larger sample, maybe 1000. What do you think happens to $v_{max}$?

Comment: @soakley I think as N increases, you are more and more likely to see every possible sample that can be rendered given a gaussian PDF with whatever $\sigma$ characterizes it... so I guess that would mean this limit is just another way of saying 'worst case'. I suppose that makes sense. The main question now becomes how is this $T$ derived in this case?

Comment: The chance that $v_{\max}$ does *not* exceed any fixed value $z$ is the chance that *all* the $v[n]$ do not exceed $z$. The independence assumption implies the latter equals $\Phi_\sigma(z)^N$ where $\Phi_\sigma$ is the CDF of the common distribution. The dependence on $N$ is clear and shows that this problem amounts to an analysis of the behavior of the right tail of the Normal CDF.

Comment: @whuber I think the following minor correction applies to your comment because $v_\max$ is the maximum absolute value, not the maximum value: $$P\{v_\max < z\} = \prod_{i=1}^N P\{-z < v_i < z\} = [2\Phi_\sigma(z) - 1]^N$$

Comment: @Dilip Thanks; you are correct--I overlooked the absolute value part of the question.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, I expanded on what you said, however I am still stuck. Please see my edits.

Comment: I believe that the [Mills ratio](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MillsRatio.html) for the standard Normal distribution will reveal what you want to know: look at its continued fraction.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, I am not seeing the connection...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on whuber's comment and my minor emendation of it, we have that for $z \geq 0$,
$$P\{v_\max < z\} = [2\Phi(z/\sigma)-1]^N = [1-2Q(z/\sigma)]^N$$ where
$\Phi(x)$ is the standard normal distribution function and $Q(x)=1-\Phi(x)$ is
its complement. Now, since $1-2Q(z) < 1$ for $z > 0$, *if* $z$ and $\sigma$
were  *constants*, that is, not functions of $N$, then as we raised a quantity
less than $1$ to ever higher powers $N$, the result would tend to $0$ as $N \to \infty$.
On the other hand, if $z/\sigma$ were such that $2Q(z/\sigma)=aN^{-1}$, then we
could use the standard result
$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{a}{N}\right)^N = e^{-a}$$
to deduce that $P\{v_\max < z\}$ converges to a positive constant (smaller
than $1$) as $N \to \infty$ and so  $P\{v_\max > z\}$ converges to a constant
greater than $0$. This is not quite good enough; we need to have 
$2Q(z/\sigma)$ go to $0$ slightly
faster than as $N^{-1}$.  What will work?  Well, a standard but weak
bound on $Q(x)$ is $$Q(x) < \frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2/2} ~~ \text{for} ~x > 0$$
and so if we choose $z = \sigma\sqrt{2\ln N}$, we get 
$2Q(z/\sigma) < e^{-\ln N} = N^{-1}$ which we just said is not a fast
enough decay with increasing $N$, but if we use the
[tighter bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/28751/15941)
$$Q(x) < \frac{1}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2},$$
with the same choice $z = \sigma\sqrt{2\ln N}$,
that extra $x$ in the denominator is giving us
an $\sqrt{\ln N}$ faster decay that suffices to allow us
to conclude that
$$P\{v_\max > \sigma\sqrt{2\ln N}\,\} \to 0~~ \text{as}~ N \to \infty.$$

Comment: (+1) Thank you @Dilip, I am unpacking and digesting what you wrote, though I believe I understand it. I upvoted this post and the one you linked to on math.se. However, i) I now understand how the selection of $z = \sigma \sqrt{2 log N}$, will make the above limit go to 1. But why the 2 inside or the sqrt? Anything particularly unique about them besides their nice/required behavior in the limit? ii) Is there a particular name for the tight bound that you derived/referenced? Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tarantula The exact value of $2Q(z/\sigma)$ is not known, but we do know that $2Q(z/\sigma) < e^{-z^2/2\sigma^2}$. We want $2Q(z/\sigma)$ to approach $0$ slightly faster than $N^{-1}$, and so we try to choose the value of $z$ such that $-z^2/2\sigma^2 = \ln N$ thus ensuring that the _upper bound_ is going to $0$ as $N^{-1}$ and so $2Q(z/\sigma)$ is decaying away at least as fast, and hopefully slightly faster. As it turns out, this is good enough. A **much harder** question would be what is the slowest growing function of $N$ that will make $2Q(z/\sigma)$ decay away faster than $N^{-1}$ ...

Comment: @Tarantula (continued) and to that question I have no answer. Perhaps people interested in _large deviations_ theory might be able to help.

Comment: That makes sense. I have accepted your answer. One last question, any reason for why you started the analysis with $P(v_{max} < z)$ instead of $P(v_{max} > z)$? I realize one gives you the other, but was wondering if there was a reason you chose the opposite of what was in the question initially.

Comment: @Tarantula Thanks. Glad to have been of help. With regard to your last query, I just followed up on Moderator whuber's comment which was there already and had been emended slightly by me. I _could_ have used $\{v_\max > z\}$ from the beginning, and that _would_ have been my inclination if I had been answering ab initio,  but I wanted to link up matters to what had been said before.